# Which package for In-line and float algorithms?

Tags: floats, listings, algorithms

I am using LyX to describe algorithms. A common scenario is that I have a snippet of pseudo code (in a float, for example) and a block of text which makes references to keywords in that pseudo code. The listings package can do this, I think, but I recall having trouble using math notation, like subscripts,  with listings. On the other hand, I have not been able to find how to use the algorithms package inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really what you asked for, but did you try the `mathescape` option in listings? (as in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809836/ddg#2809941))

It seems to do what you want for sub/superscripts (but a more precise example might lead to a different answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do anything special, keywords in the algorithms package are simply bold, so you could format those yourself, i.e. as in `\mathbf{while}`, when you need to refer to those keywords in the text.